ODBC connection to filemaker in QGIS
I am trying to create an ODBC connection between QGIS and a filemaker DB.
I have the filemaker driver setup and a connection created using the windows administrator, this works fine when tested.

When I try to connect in QGIS I get an "Unable to initialize ODBC connection to DSN" error which I think means there is some sort of mismatch going on. The Q&As I have found are mostly very old and reference using an alternative administrator which isn't included in Windows 11 or using a 32bit driver which I might try.


I have a similar problem.  Did you find a solution?  I either get “unable to initialize…” or QGIS crashes

No joy so far, been looking at others options
